# Setting up pyrocms/codeigniter on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I am having trouble getting a project to work that I have inherited and not setup myself. I install the DB and make sure the file/folder permissions are correct -- but I am getting this error when I try to get to the local site -

> This domain is not set up correctly. Please go to http://localhost/myproject/sites and log in to add this site.

I get that error again when I go to that URL... so not exactly helpful on 'adding sites'.

Is there any way to setup a local site in the database manually without using the installer?

Comment: What kind of OS you working on? In future use relevant tags.

Comment: My bad, OSX -- but I replicated the same error on both mac and PC.

Comment: What kind of installer you are talking about in original post? Have you successfully made apache (web server) work? Can you perhaps include some screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the field "domain" in the table "core_sites" in your PyroCMS DB.
This field should be set to the domain you're open the website on.

This is usually caused if you're installing PyroCMS through a different URL, than you use to open the website.

e. g.

install through http://dev-server/website/pyrocms/installer, but call the website on http://pyrodev.local because you've set up a virtual host and corresponding DNS entries.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I had just taken over an existing repo so it was already all installed, this was the problem.  Thanks!